# Change Vertex Position During Rig Animation

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, vertices

I couldn't find a solution to this problem.

I have my character all rigged and made a walk cycle. I parented another mesh with the rig which are the character's clothes. When he starts walking though the clothes are not always perfectly covering his body parts, so that his leg glitches through the cloth, which is awful of course!

[image]

I thought I go through every frame and correct the glitches by changing the vertex positions of my cloth mesh. However I seem not to be able to change the vertices within the "Pose Mode/Armature Animation Sequence", when I go into edit mode the clothes revert to the rest pose and no animation can be played.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the modifier panel for your object, activate "Display modifier in edit mode" and "Adjust edit cage to modifier result" for the Armature modifier:

[image]